# Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined at login.js:2

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I know this might be a dumb question but I just started my web app project and I'm having a hard time initializing firebase to use its features in other files. I'm getting this error in my login.js file.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined at login.js:2

It's always saying that firebase is not defined. Did I do the initialization in my HTML file wrong? Or do I need to include the block in my js file as well? I tried a lot of ways but couldn't find the problem.
login.html

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
    <script src="login.js"></script>
    <script src="firebase.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FileTrans</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="p1">Welcome</p>
    <p id="p2">Please login to your account</p>
    <br><br>
    <div class="input_field">

      <form action="">
        <label for="email">Email address:</label><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email@email.com" required><br><br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Must be longer than 6 characters" required><br><br>
        <input type="button" id="login" name="login" value="LOGIN" onclick="loginToFirebase();">
      </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script>
        var firebaseConfig = {
            ...hiden due to safety reasons
          };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        firebase.analytics();
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

login.js

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
function loginToFirebase() {
 var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
 var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
 console.log("email is: "+email + " and password is: "+ password);
 //auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword();
}
```

Comment: add `<script src="login.js"></script>` after `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>`

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe that was the problem. Thank you so much. And from now on I need to pay more attention to the ordering of my code.

Comment: Glad I could help :)